# PgfPlots ybar and ybar stacked conflict

Tags: pgfplots

I have one document with 2 documents included. In the first document I have a pgfPlot with `\pgfplotsset{
ybar stacked, ...etc }` and in the second one `\pgfplotsset{
ybar, ..etc }`, but the first pgfplotsset goes in  conflict with the second, and also the second document has "ybar stacked" option active.

Here the documents:

Main:

```
 \begin{document}

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\end{document}
```

chapter1

```
    \pgfplotsset{
ybar stacked, 
enlargelimits =0.05,
legend style ={at={(0.5,-0.5)},
anchor=north,
legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Ore},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
symbolic x coords={Enrico Rotundo,Federico Poli,Giacomo Fornari,Gianluca Donato,Luca De Franceschi,Nicolò Tresoldi,Serena Girardi}
}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\input{columnChart_rr}
\legend{amministratore, analista, progettista, programmatore, responsabile, verificatore}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Ore per componente, periodo di analisi}
\end{figure}
```

chapter2

```
\pgfplotsset{
ybar, 
enlargelimits =0.10,
legend style ={at={(0.5,-0.5)},
anchor=north,
legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Ore},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
symbolic x coords={Amministratore, Analista, Progettista, Programmatore, Responsabile, Verificatore},
}


    \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\input{columnChart_consuntivo_rr}
\legend{preventivate,consumate}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Differenza preventivo consuntivo per ruolo, periodo di analisi}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that chapter2 use ybar stacked option which is in chapter1 file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deactivate the stacking by setting `stack plots=false`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9, samples=5}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{ybar stacked}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{ybar, stack plots=false}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can keep the `ybar stacked` option local by supplying it to the `axis` environment directly, instead of setting it globally using `\pgfplotsset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9, samples=5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```