# Deactivate ybar to use ybar stacked

Tags: pgfplots

I have a template that globally sets the `ybar` option. However, I would like to use `ybar stacked`. When combining both, the output bars are shifted to the right as in the example below. How can I reset the effect of `ybar` without removing it from the global options?

The problem is very similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156849/pgfplots-ybar-and-ybar-stacked-conflict), but it is the other way around.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ybar} % global option that can not be removed
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: ybar mixed with ybar stacked]

Comment: Add `bar shift=0pt` to the axis options: `\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,bar shift=0pt]`

Comment: Sounds like a bad plan to globally set `ybar`, why can't you remove it?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Because it is a plot template that was originally only meant to be used for conventional bar plots. Now it is in use by dozens of plots and either I have to touch all of them or add a `bar shift=0pt` to one of them, as @esdd suggested, which is working very good for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `bar shift=0pt` to the axis options:

```
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,bar shift=0pt]
```

[image]

Additional remark: Set a `compat` immediatelly after loading `pgfplots`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% <- add this after loading pgfplots, current version is 1.15
\pgfplotsset{ybar} % global option that can not be removed
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
      bar shift=0pt% <- added
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```